# Polymorphic many to one relationship sqlalchemy

Tags: database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here are my classes:

```
class CatalogEntryItem(db.Model):
     __tablename__="catalog_entry_items"
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     item_type = db.Column(db.String(500))
     item_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

     #polymorphic relationship to product and service
     __mapper_args__ = {
         "polymorphic_identity":"catalog_entry_items",
         "polymorphic_on": "item_type",
     }

class Product(CatalogEntryItem):
     __tablename__="products"
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = db.Column(db.String(500), index=False, unique=False, nullable=False)
     price = db.Column(db.String, index=False)    

     __mapper_args__ = {
         "polymorphic_identity":'product'
     }

     def __repr__(self):
         return '<Product {}>'.format(self.name)

class Service(CatalogEntryItem):
     __tablename__="services"
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = db.Column(db.String(500), index=False, unique=False, nullable=False)
     price = db.Column(db.String, index=False)    

     __mapper_args__ = {
         "polymorphic_identity":'service'
     }

     def __repr__(self):
         return '<Service{}>'.format(self.name)
```

First, I get a an error - "Please ensure the inheriting table has a foreign
key relationship to the inherited table, or provide an 'on clause' using the 'inheri
t_condition' mapper argument." I understand that sqlalchemy is looking for a foreign key in the product and service class, as specified by the documentation, however the behavior I'm looking for is that of a many-to-one relationship. Say I create a new catalog entry item, I can choose any number of products and services, with item_type distinguishing between the 2 as a polymorphic relationship and ideally item_id identifying the actual instance of product or service. I initially thought about doing this with 2 separate foreign keys, but I believe this way would be much slicker, and would result in less null values. The thing is, if I declare item_id as a foreign key, it would be a key to which class? Can I foreign key to the item_type? any help would be greatly appreciated.